# Pandas groupby when group criteria repeat

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
A B C
a b  1
c d  1
e f 2
g h 2
i j 2
K l 1
J K 1
L M  1
```

I have a dataset that looks something like this. I want to group them based on C. The data is sequential and I want to give unique ids to each group. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please format your data into a table structure, what you expect the final results to look like, and what you have already tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical trick is to use the non-equality between successive rows (`True` where this happens), then a cumulative sum to forward fill and increment the `True`s as increasing numerical values.

Using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html), then [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to form the group. [`ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) to get the group ID:

```
grouper = df['C'].ne(df['C'].shift()).cumsum()
df['group'] = df.groupby(grouper).ngroup()
```

Or with [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), and `ne` then `cumsum`:

```
grouper = df['C'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
```

output:

```
   A  B  C  group
0  a  b  1      0
1  c  d  1      0
2  e  f  2      1
3  g  h  2      1
4  i  j  2      1
5  K  l  1      2
6  J  K  1      2
7  L  M  1      2
```

Intermediates of the logic to construct the grouper:

```
   C  non-eq  implicit int  cumsum
0  1    True             1       1
1  1   False             0       1
2  2    True             1       2
3  2   False             0       2
4  2   False             0       2
5  1    True             1       3
6  1   False             0       3
7  1   False             0       3
```